# My virtual environment is having access to global packages

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I have `virtualenv 15.1.0` installed. The problem is that when I create a virtual environment with

```
virtualenv venv
```

and then activate it, it will have access to packages installed globally (`django-admin` for example). This happens although it is mentioned in `virtualenv` reference guide [here](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/#cmdoption-no-site-packages) that:

> Not having access to global site-packages is now the default behavior.

Also, I want to mention that running `pip3 freeze` while the virtual environment is activated prints nothing.

Comment: Try `virtualenv --no-site-packages` explicit. As for `pip3 freeze` — are there packages installed with `pip3`?

Comment: Even with `virtualenv --no-site-packages`, it is the same. As for `pip3 freeze`, nothing is installed (when the virtual environment is activated)

Answer (score 0):

Check your environment variables? Such as `$PATH`, `$PYTHONPATH`.

virtualenv just manipulate your environment variables.

Comment: `$PYTHONPATH` is the same whether the virtual environment is activated or deactivated. It is empty. `$PATH` is also the same except that when the virtual environment is activated, the path to `venv/bin` is placed before other paths.