# My virtual environment can access global packages even specifying not to

Tags: git, flask, virtualenv, python-3.6, ubuntu-18.04

I have created a python virtual environment as part of a Flask project. Despite specifying that I do not want the venv to have access to my machine packages it does so when a package is missing in the venv.

I have tried `virtualenv` with and without the `--no-site-packages` instruction. I have also created a blank text file named `no-global-site-packages.txt` in my venv python package (`venv/lib/python3.6/no-global-site-packages.txt`).

My `$PYTHONPATH` is empty. And my original venv is a git repo, but for the purpose of figuring this issue out I have tried non-git folders with the same results.

With my virgin venv activated I get:

```
which python
>> /venv/bin/python
which pip
>> /venv/bin/pip
```

which what I expected, however I get:

```
which flask
>> /usr/bin/flask
```

Instead of crashing for not been installed flask in the venv.

I saw this question but non of the proposed solutions worked:
[My virtual environment is having access to global packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45961748/my-virtual-environment-is-having-access-to-global-packages)

Anyone knows what is the problem here? What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have `flask` installed in the venv? From the question I don't see you have access to the global `site-packages`, you only showed that you've `flask` installed globally and *its script* (not packages) is accessible because it's in the `$PATH`. If you don't have installed `flask` in the venv nothing prevent the system to access the script. When you install `flask` in the venv it will shadow the globally installed `flask`.

Comment: Even if `/usr/bin/flask` can be run it doesn't mean it has access to your virtualenv — it can have shebang `/usr/bin/python` and that python uses the global packages. The only way to test if your virtualenv is separated from the global packages is to test *packages*: `python -c "import flask"`; if you don't have `flask` installed the command fails.